# UIView bounces?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

I have a UIView at the very bottom of my nib. I want it's height to grow, but make it appear as if it is not moving in position, just growing. Then afterwards shrink the height back to it's original height without any movement except the height. Unfortunately, it bounces in y positioning. It will grow correctly, but it will move from the bottom of the screen. Can anybody tell me why?

Here is what it should look like, hover over the black box,(what the UIView should do):

http://jsfiddle.net/hqJm9/

Here is what I am using in objective c with weird results (bouncing)

on button click:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations: ^{
                CGRect blackBackgroundFrame = self.blackBackground.frame;
                blackBackgroundFrame.size.height += 50;
                self.blackBackground.frame = blackBackgroundFrame;

                self.blackBackground.center = CGPointMake(self.blackBackground.center.x, self.blackBackground.center.y - 50);

}];
```

button click again:

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations: ^{
                CGRect blackBackgroundFrame = self.blackBackground.frame;
                blackBackgroundFrame.size.height -= 50;
                [self.blackBackground setFrame:blackBackgroundFrame];
                self.blackBackground.center = CGPointMake(self.blackBackground.center.x, self.blackBackground.center.y + 50);
    }];
```

Why does it move from the bottom? How can I fix this?? Thanks

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is likely bouncing because you are trying to animate the center and frame simultaneously. Instead, try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations: ^{
            CGRect originalFrame = self.blackBackground.frame;
            self.blackBackground.frame = CGRectMake(originalFrame.origin.x,
                                                    originalFrame.origin.y-50,
                                                    originalFrame.size.width,
                                                    originalFrame.size.height+50);
}];
```

and

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations: ^{
            CGRect originalFrame = self.blackBackground.frame;
            self.blackBackground.frame = CGRectMake(originalFrame.origin.x,
                                                    originalFrame.origin.y+50,
                                                    originalFrame.size.width,
                                                    originalFrame.size.height-50);
}];
```

And the view should animate properly.

EDIT: After closer inspection and some experimentation it looks like the issues is actually the fact that you are changing the center by 50 pixels. What you are doing here should work just fine if you remember that the center is the halfway point, so an increase in height by 50 only changes the center by 25.

Comment: This was indeed the problem!! Thank you very much Jumhyn. I'll remember to do it this way next time! Will accept your answer when the limit is up.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually slightly misguided in my thinking, check my edit for the real issue with your code. In general though if you can just set the frame instead of doing frame and center it's better to do that, unless the math to calculate it is way more complicated.